# Connection to PivotChart fails

Tags: excel

I have PivotCharts in my excel file that work perfectly when i connect them for the first time. I use : Insert-PivotChart-use an external data source (it is csv btw), I proceed to make all graphs.
Tomorrow when I open same excel file I cant refresh source data and it wont allow me to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put your pivot data into a sheet, and call it from there, rather that straight from external

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldnt the same problem happen with refreshing of the table?

Comment: If the data is in a set sheet in excel, refreshing the data will just pull from that sheet - no problems there

Comment: I tried and it worked great, but when I opened the file again it said there was an error with connection and that it had to delete them to open workbook.